# How to save arraylist with JSON properly (Always returning "" as only result)

Tags: java, android

I have a button that adds items to a arraylist. I know that the items are being added because I can do the following and it prints the appropriate size.

```
System.out.println(array.size());
```

Now I want to save that array list using json and then reload it for use. When I save it and reload it as seen below this results in my new arraylist containing nothing. I am either not saving correctly or not loading correctly.

Here is where I save the arraylist

```
public void correct(View view)
{
TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
result.setText("Correct");

if (!questionsCorrect.contains(questionsArray[position]))
{
    questionsCorrect.add(questionsArray[position]);
    String temp = questionsArray[position];
    if (questionsWrong.contains(questionsArray[position]))
    {
        questionsWrong.remove(temp);
    }
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonSubjectOne = gson.toJson(questionsCorrect);
numberCorrect = (questionsCorrect.size()) - 1;
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("subjectOnePrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("subjectOneNumberCorrect", numberCorrect);
editor.putString("jsonSubjectOne", jsonSubjectOne);
editor.commit();
```

}

Now I want to load my arraylist on create

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.subjectone);

questionsCorrect.add("");

TextView question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionTV);
Button showPrevious = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousQuestion);
showPrevious.setText("Home");
question.setText(questionsArray[0]);

Button incorrect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.incorrect);
Button correct = (Button)findViewById(R.id.correct);
TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

incorrect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
correct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
result.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Gson gson=new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
String jsonSubjectOne = gson.toJson(questionsCorrect);
ArrayList<String> questionsCorrect=new ArrayList<String>();
questionsCorrect=gson.fromJson(jsonSubjectOne, type);

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("subjectOnePrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
numberCorrect = sharedPref.getInt("mySetting", 0);
```

}

Now, when I load this new arraylist from what was saved and print it I only get "" as a result regardless of what was added to the arraylist.

Comment: First arraylist is convert in string then save in SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to utilize [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to solve your issue. The main idea is to convert your ArrayList in a String object, save this String object with SharedPreferences and then retrieve the String object to convert back to your ArrayList

To achieve this result: 
Import Gson through gradle,

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(questionsCorrect);
```

and then save this json with SharedPreferences as you'd do with a String object.

To retrieve your ArrayList

```
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
```

Retrieve through SharedPreferences the String object you saved. Let's call it again json

```
    ArrayList<String> questionsCorrectRetrieved=new ArrayList<String>();   
    questionsCorrectRetrieved=gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Please note that Type type specify what kind of object you want to retrieve. You can save ArrayList or any other object

Comment: I added code in my question to show how I tried using your suggestion but I am getting an error when I try to load it. It is explained in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, cannot add a comment to your post because of my low reputation.

 Reading your updated .java I cannot find any declaration for "json"

You should write something like this

   `String json=sharedPref.getString("your_tag", "default_string");`

with json that stores your ArrayList as String. 
String json now can be used to reconvert (deserialize) from String to your ArrayList.

Comment: I think I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how JSON worked. After doing some research and returning to your code I was able to achieve my results. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this, it may help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private Editor mEditor;
    private Button mDataGet;
    private TextView mData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDataGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_data);
        mData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_data);
        saveData();
        getData();

    }

    private void getData() {
        mDataGet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Set<String> resultSet = new HashSet<>();
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                resultSet = mSharedPreferences.getStringSet("test", null);
                if (resultSet.size() > 0) {
                    resultSet.iterator();
                    for (String s : resultSet) {
                        sb.append(s + "\n");
                    }
                    mData.setText(sb.toString());
                } else {
                    mData.setText("sb is null");
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void saveData() {
        Set<String> testSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            testSet.add("test" + i);
            Log.i("write in set  --", "test" + i);
        }
        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("testsp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        mEditor.putStringSet("test", testSet);
        mEditor.commit();
    }

}
```